# I am getting "com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 26))" in WSO2 MI 4.2.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I am getting trying to read XML file which is having white space character as shown below.
this is proxy reading the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="readXMLwithWhiteCharacters" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <fileconnector.read>
                <source>file:///opt/data/sample.xml</source>
                <contentType>application/xml</contentType>
                <filePattern>.*/.xml</filePattern>
            </fileconnector.read>
            <property expression="json-eval($)" name="file-content" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="full">
                <property expression="get-property('file-content')" name="log-json-response"/>
            </log>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
--------------------------------------
    <readone>
        <value> </value>
    </readone>
```

Sample XML File is like above which is having the Char26 in value tag shows like ' '.
So when try reading the file it gives given error.
Even when I am trying to add XMLOutputFactory.properties file as per given in the documentation of MI still I am getting the same error.
https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/setup/message_builders_formatters/message-builders-and-formatters/

```
Error:
[2023-07-07 02:51:50,296] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.connector.util.ResultPayloadCreate} - Error while processing the file/folder org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 26))
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,9]
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildNext(OMElementImpl.java:653)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getFirstOMChild(OMElementImpl.java:670)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getChildren(OMElementImpl.java:352)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:554)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:879)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:556)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:879)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:556)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:879)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:230)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serialize(OMSerializableImpl.java:125)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serialize(OMSerializableImpl.java:113)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.toString(OMElementImpl.java:992)
        at org.wso2.carbon.connector.util.ResultPayloadCreate.buildFile(ResultPayloadCreate.java:183)
        at org.wso2.carbon.connector.FileRead.connect(FileRead.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.connector.core.AbstractConnector.mediate(AbstractConnector.java:32)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.updateInstancePropertiesAndMediate(ClassMediator.java:178)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:110)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:72)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(TemplateMediator.java:136)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:170)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:93)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:110)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:72)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:240)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector.execute(MessageInjector.java:336)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.mediation.ntask.NTaskAdapter.execute(NTaskAdapter.java:105)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:63)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 26))
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,9]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwInvalidSpace(StreamScanner.java:666)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readTextPrimary(BasicStreamReader.java:4576)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2879)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1072)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 37 more
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible sample, so we can better understand the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the information you shared. Can you share your `deployment.toml` as well?

Comment: deployment.toml is the basic one, I have not changed anything there